# can't read from FIFO?

Tags: python, linux, django, apache

I am trying to create a utility for a web application I have deployed on a remote server which will allow me to take messages created by my web application and pipe them to a process running on the same machine which simply outputs these messages on the terminal.  The server part of this utility simply takes a message and writes it out to my FIFO file:

```
def log_str(msg):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,FIFO_DIR)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,FIFO_DIR))

    #see if the FIFO exists, if not create it
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,FIFO_DIR,FIFO_NAME)):
        os.mkfifo(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, FIFO_DIR, FIFO_NAME))

    fd = os.open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,FIFO_DIR,FIFO_NAME), os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    os.write(fd, msg)

    return True
```

However, when I call this function from within one of my views to test it, it reports `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/async_testtmp'`

I have a feeling that this could be due to issues with the configuration of my apache web server but I am not sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does your script have file creation and write permission in that directory?

Comment: Nope!  Turns out apache has its own user and doesn't use root.  Seems obvious in retrospect but it took me a bit of investigation to figure that out.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3285713: That's actually a standard setup that almost all servers use. Either they run as `nobody` or a special user, or they run as `root` just long enough to bind a low-numbered port and then drop privs to `nobody` or a special user. That way, if someone finds a way to exploit the server, they can only affect things that `nobody` has access to, which is generally nothing important.

Comment: Also, for future reference, don't just show the error, show which line the error comes from (and the whole traceback, if you have one). Not all problems are this obvious.